# Xamarin, Android; GPS: Why is my app going into "OnProviderEnabled"?

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, xamarin.android

When I implement the ILocationManager, VS automatically adds this interface:

```
public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Now, after it initialized the location manager, my app jumps into the "OnProviderEnabled" function. But why is that? Of course, it crashes and gives me:

"System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented."

I don't even know what to put here. In the example code on GitHub, these are just empty methods.

So what am I missing?

THanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OnProviderEnabled : Called when the provider is enabled by the user.

When the `LocationManager` that you have registered a listener is enabled (`isProviderEnabled`) your `OnProviderEnabled` method will be called, there is a matching `OnProviderDisabled` method. If the GPS is already enabled in the system setting, `OnProviderEnabled` is called immediately.

If the user toggles the GPS off (and on) after you have already registered the listener, these methods will be called and your application might need to react to that, maybe updating a screen icon, displaying a Toast/Dialog, etc...

If your app/code does not care about the state of the provider, remove the  `NotImplementedException` and leave the method call empty.